# How to send a document to Docusign via Power Automate?

Tags: docusignapi, power-automate

I seem to be missing some steps adding a  Flow (Power Automate) to send document to Docusign, I was successful using the "Send Envelope using Template" but I cant seem to get a non template document to send. i.e adding recipients and envelope ID.

Comment: Would you include the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not currently supported in the DocuSign Flow Connector.
There are lots of workarounds, including creating your own Flow connector.
You can use a template if you want.
Using a document directly is not available at this time and no plans that I know of to add it.

Comment: Hello Inbar. It's old thread but still I want to check if there are no plans yet or will be introduce in near future?

Comment: I don't know the answer, please email feedback@docusign.com

Answer (score 0):

I've done this but created my own connector. Just wondering how to then get the completed documents to sharepoint as I don't have the envelope id in my connector currently.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30357581)

Comment: Make sure you include the code of your connector in the question you ask about this.