# Starting point for DocuSign in Power Automate?

Tags: docusignapi, power-automate

This is possibly a duplicate of [How to send a document to Docusign via Power Automate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880006/how-to-send-a-document-to-docusign-via-power-automate)

I see that the following flow objects for DocuSign. I would guess the "Send envelope" is the correct 2nd step, but how do I go about creating an Envelope? I would have expected to see something like "Create envelope using Document", like Adobe Sign offers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a custom connector, cannot use out of the box connector.

https://www.docusign.com.au/blog/get-the-flow-sending-docusign-envelopes-microsoft-power-automate

Explains how to do a custom connector.

Comment: Did you just copy-paste this document? https://www.docusign.com.au/blog/get-the-flow-sending-docusign-envelopes-microsoft-power-automate - if so, that is what I'm currently using, but doesn't use the actual connector built by DocuSign, it uses the custom connector approach.

Comment: yes, thanks, I'll update to the link. You cannot do this with the out-of-the-box connector, you have to use a customer connector.